# How can I replace only plus sign (multiple occurrence) from a string without any text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace multiple (++++++) signs with blank space?

Example: `var string = "+++++++++++++++++";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var string = "+++++++++++++++++";
string = string.replace(/\+*/g, '');
console.log(string.length);
```

Comment: Hello there, I tried your code, the snippet you presented seems to work just fine. I am indeed grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'abc++++++def++++frberbf++fsvsf';
const newstr = str.replace(/(.)\+{2,}/g, ' ');
console.log(newstr);
```